# How to save multiple line selections made when editing with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I need to find a way to save a file with specific lines and areas preselected. I use sublime text to change many text areas and image paths in a template. Only text and images will vary in the template.Instead of selecting all the areas again and copy/paste, I would like to find a way to keep my selected areas saved somewhere, so when I edit the template, I will just need to paste.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there really isn't a way to save selections in files after they're closed. However, the good news is you may not have to. You can set up a [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) with your template, and insert fields that you can tab through and paste in the information you need. As an example, here's a small snippet for a simple HTML document template:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>${1:Default}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${2:main.css}">
</head>
<body>
    <p>$0</p>
</body>
</html>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>mytemplate</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save the file in your `Packages/User` folder (`Packages` is accessible via `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`) as `mytemplate.sublime-snippet`. Then, open a new file with the syntax set to HTML. You can now type `mytemplate` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the contents between `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` will be inserted. Field 1 (the title) will be highlighted, with `Default` as the default value. Type or paste in your desired value and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and now field 2 (the stylesheet href) will be highlighted, with a default value of `main.css`. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, and your cursor will now be at the `$0` exit point. You can add as many fields as you want, with or without default values. See the [snippets reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html) and the link above for more information and additional variables.

Good luck!